# Calculation of probability based on population distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

In one city there are ninety percent who like peas, and ten percent who do not like peas, in that city there is a road driven by one hundred people who live in the city at any one hour, can I claim that out of those one hundred people there is a probability that there will be at least one person who does not like peas?

I will emphasize that my question is in principle, is there a probabilistic determination in things that have nothing to do with each other, i.e. there is no particular reason to make people who like or dislike the peas drive precisely on this road, does the population distribution in one figure affect the probability of finding each group?

EDIT:

Maybe I can not clarify myself

My question is - a person who loves peas, has no reason to drive on this road more than a person who did not like peas, so there is no circumstantial connection between love of peas and road travel, is there still an effect of statistics on the distribution of people on this road, or no statistical consistency, and that Like the "Wild West."

I hope I am now more understood

Comment: Can you clarity these two phrases: "here is a probability that there will be at least one person who does not like peas?" and "in principle, is there a probabilistic determination in things that have nothing to do with each other,"

Comment: Subject to that clarification, and assuming Independence, maybe $1-(.1)^{100}.$

Comment: @Bey I edited the post

Answer (score 2):

More clarity on the assumptions is needed. If the 100 people driving on the road is a metaphor for a random sample (i.e. liking peas is independent and identically distributed across the 100 people), and assuming the the 90% and 10% figures are frequentist interpretations of population probabilities, then the probability at least one driver does not like peas is one minus the probability that all like peas, which is $1-.9^{100}.$

If you think there is some "connection" between driving on the road and liking peas such that independence is not a valid assumption, then you need more information on that dependence structure to compute the probability.